# Convergence in Egorov's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Egorov's theorem is used often used to prove the dominated convergence theorem. The proof I am currently reading says that according to Egorov's theorem and absolute continuity of the Lebesgue integral, we can choose a $\delta > 0$ and a set $B$ such that $\mu(B) < \delta$ and $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly on $C = A \setminus B$ etc.

Should it be obvious that there is uniform convergence not only on $B$, but also on its complement? 
The theorem itself only mentions that for every $\delta>0$ there exists such a set $B \subset A$ that $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly on $B$ and $\mu(A\setminus B) < \delta$

Why is it possible to conclude that uniform convergence is preserved on $A\setminus B$?

Comment: What do you mean  "uniform converges exists not only on , but also on its complement"?

Comment: You only have uniform converges on $A\backslash B$. If you add $B$ you don't have uniform converges anymore.

Comment: The example you may want to keep in mind is $f_n=x^n$ with $A=[0,1]$. Then $f_n$ convergence uniformly to $0$ only if you remove an interval around $1$.

Comment: I will try to clarify my question. I understand Egorov's theorem this way: we have a.e convergence on $A$. For any $\delta > 0$ we can find such a set $B \subset A$ that $\mu(A\setminus B) < \delta$ and $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly on $B$. 

The textbook I am currently reading, however, uses this theorem and says the following: 
"We have a.e convergence on $D$. Then there is $E \subset D$ such that $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $D \setminus E$. Shouldn't it be uniformly convergent on $E$ instead?

Comment: You introduce $C$ and never use it again? Then you mangle the roles of $B$ and $A\setminus B$ in paragraph 2. This indeed has a happy ending, but you need to be more precise in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your original post and some of the exchanges in the comments, if I am understanding your confusion correctly, the way you normally present Egorov's theorem is as follows:

**Accustomed statement of Egorov:** Suppose $\mu(A) < \infty$ and $f_n$ is a sequence of measurable functions that converge a.e. to $f$ on $A$. Then for each $\delta>0$, there is a measurable set $B\subset A$ such that $\mu(A\smallsetminus B) < \delta$ and such that $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $B$.

The version you are reading now in this proof is

**New version:** Suppose $\mu(A) < \infty$ and $f_n$ is a sequence of measurable functions that converge a.e. to $f$ on $A$. Then for each $\delta>0$, there is a measurable set $B\subset A$ such that $\mu(B) < \delta$ and such that $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $A\smallsetminus B$.

Really, these are saying the same thing: in each case, the claim is that for any $\delta>0$ we like, we can find a "small set," i.e., one whose measure is less than $\delta$, such that $f_n\to f$ uniformly on the complement of that small set. In what I am calling the accustomed statement of Egorov's theorem, the small set is $A\smallsetminus B$. In what I am calling the new version, the small set is $B$.